# Overwriting an S3 Generic Method While Keeping Previous Methods R

Tags: r

I could have sworn I searched for this topic way back when and found something, but I cannot find that solution - so apologies if this is a repeat.

When you are adding your own generic method to an existing S3 method built into R (like print, summary, ect), but need to add something to method dispatch, how does that work? So for example, if `print` didn't have an ellipsis (and perhaps some other parameters), could I simply do something like this (and maintain all of the other generic methods that print had.)

```
print <- function(x, new_param_one, new_param_two, ...) { 
    UseMethod("print")
} 

print.crazy_obj <- function(x, ect, ...) { 
#STUFF
}
```

And then print.data.frame, and all of the other generic methods would still exist? Or what is the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you would want to overwrite the generic. In your question you say

> So for example, if print didn't have an ellipsis

But the S3 generic methods all *do* have an ellipsis (at least I can't think of or find any that don't). It is the ellipsis that provides the functionality you are looking for.

Suppose you have a function that creates a new class:

```r
crazy_obj <- function(x) structure(x, class = "crazy_obj")

y <- crazy_obj("biscuit")
```

You can give the `print.crazy_obj` method whatever parameters you like; these will be passed from the generic via the ellipsis:

```
print.crazy_obj <- function(x, n = 1, ...) print(paste(rep("crazy", n), x))
```

So now we can do:

```r
print(y)
#> [1] "crazy biscuit"

print(y, 4)
#> [1] "crazy biscuit" "crazy biscuit" "crazy biscuit" "crazy biscuit"
```